# JQuery returning undefined from PHP JSON string

Tags: php, jquery

I am trying this JQuery code:

```
val = $(this).val();
var data = {
    "action": "test"
};
data = $(this).serialize() + "&" + $.param(data);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "?getCustomer=1&sequence="+val+"",
    data: data,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data["sequence"]);
    }
});
```

but the `alert` is returning `undefined`

if i check the URL (`?getCustomer=1&sequence=4`) i get this returned:

```
[{"sequence":"53"}]
```

so the sequence value is definately the

this is what shows in the console:

```
[Object]0: Objectsequence: "112"__proto__: Objectlength: 1__proto__: Array[0]concat: concat()constructor: Array()copyWithin: copyWithin()entries: entries()every: every()fill: fill()filter: filter()find: find()findIndex: findIndex()forEach: forEach()indexOf: indexOf()join: join()keys: keys()lastIndexOf: lastIndexOf()length: 0map: map()pop: pop()push: push()reduce: reduce()reduceRight: reduceRight()reverse: reverse()shift: shift()slice: slice()some: some()sort: sort()splice: splice()toLocaleString: toLocaleString()toString: toString()unshift: unshift()Symbol(Symbol.iterator): values()Symbol(Symbol.unscopables): Object__proto__: Object
```

Comment: What does console.log(data) show ?

Comment: check my update - wouldnt fit in comments

Comment: try `data.sequence` instead.  json is an object, not an array.  you can see that by the console.log results.

Comment: It returns an array, but you're accessing it like an object?

Comment: just tried data.sequence but still undefined

Comment: Data is an array with one item therein. That item is an object with a property named `sequence`. So you need to access the first item in the array (index `0`), then access its `sequence` property: `data[0].sequence`

Comment: How about: `alert(data[0]['sequence'])`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You misunderstood your json. Change

```
alert(data["sequence"]);
```

With

```
alert(data[0]["sequence"]);
```

or better

```
alert(data[0].sequence );
```

Answer (score 0):

`[{"sequence":"53"}]` is an array, the first element of which is an object with a sequence member. You need to `alert(data[0]['sequence'])`.